# Detect parent click button with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a page with two buttons, one Button opens a popup window with the next function:

```
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  my_window=window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
```

and I need to detect from that window (my_window) when the second button in the parent page is clicked and raise an alert.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do `my_window.alert("hey")` in the click event for the second button in the parent window. If you want to access the parent window from the child window (to add an event, for example), use `window.opener` in the child window.

```
button2.onclick = function (e) {
   my_window.buttonTwoHasBeenClicked(); // this is defined in the child window.. once executed it means the button has been clicked.
}
```

If you want to define the event from *within* the child window:

```
// put this in your child window javascript source
// also change "button2" to whatever your second button's ID is.
window.opener.getElementById("button2").onclick = function () {
   alert("button has been clicked on parent window");
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks but what I need is that the child window detects IF the parent button was clicked, the alert is just to see if it works.

Thanks

Comment: @notforever: Yes, I know. You would need a click handler, no matter where it was defined in. In that click handle you would call a function in your `my_window` reference to let the other window "know" the button has been clicked.

Comment: I am sorry I am a a newbie, could you give me an example please, I don't know how to reference parent button from my window. Thanks

Comment: @notforever: Try out the second snippet I added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to put code on the child window using window.opener, like this:

```
function registerWithParent() {
    window.opener.registerCallback(myCallback);
}
```

you can call than on body onload event.

```
<body onload="registerWithParent()">
```

Then you have JS code on the parent window like this:

```
var theCallback;
function registerCallback(fn) {
    theCallback = fn;
}
```

Then your HTML on the parent is like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="theCallback()" value="The 2nd button">
```